# DocuSign add signature fields without using x and y coordinates on a PDF document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I wanted to add signature fields without using X and Y coordinations. 
My existing flattened pdf files will contain several signature fields on them.
I want to find a way to generate signature fields in DocuSign with existing signature locations. The original PDF its XFA type I flatten pdf before send it to DocuSign. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Without using this method**

```
 signHere.XPosition = "100";
 signHere.YPosition = "150";
```

Comment: Please share atleast code snippet and tell what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually place any tab at a location based on document content. For instance, if you had the text "Please Sign Here" somewhere in your document, you can place any tag right on or near this text very easily, for example. To do this you could use the following JSON to define your tab(s):

```
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:" 
        }
    ]
}
```

The above example would place a signature tab where the text "Please Sign Here" is present on the pdf. One common approach that many developers take here is to embed content into the documents themselves such as the string \s1 for example. They additionally set the font color to the same color as the background where the string is placed (usually white) and this in turn makes the string \s1 invisible so that the recipient only sees the DocuSign tab at this location.

Other option available with PDF is, if you have PDF Form fields and if it as per DS standards then DocuSign can convert those PDF form fields to DocuSign Tabs. For instance, if Adobe form field name contains DocuSignSignHere or eSignSignHere then automatically DocuSign will put a DocuSign SignHere Tab in place of this form field. You can checkout complete list [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor).